# Qt program crashes on unsuccessful connect to QPSQL

Tags: postgresql, qt

I'm trying to connect to QPSQL Database via crossover cable or wireless. When I enter the correct details it's all fine but if I enter the incorrect details the program crashes instead of giving me the qDebug message why?

```
const char* driverName = "QPSQL";
QSQLDbHelper* qSQLDbHelper = new QSQLDbHelper(driverName);
postgres_db = qSQLDbHelper->connect(host,database,username,password,port);

if(postgres_db->open())
{
    qDebug() <<"Opened Postgres Database"<< postgres_db->open();
}
else
{
    qDebug() << "Something went Wrong:" << postgres_db->lastError().text();
}
qSQLDbHelper->disConnect();
delete qSQLDbHelper;

void QSQLDbHelper::disConnect()
{
    qDebug() << "Disconnected From Postgres Database!";
    postgres_db->close();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On unsuccessful connection `connect()` returns NULL:

```
QSqlDatabase* QSQLDbHelper::connect( const QString& server,
                                     const QString& databaseName,
                                     const QString& userName,
                                     const QString& password )
{
    db->setConnectOptions();
    db->setHostName(server);
    db->setDatabaseName(databaseName);
    db->setUserName(userName);
    db->setPassword(password);

    if(db->open()) {
        return db;
    }
    else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

So you are doing that:

```
qDebug() << "Something went Wrong:" << NULL->lastError().text();
```

EDIT: To add a few points to my answer:

You are doing `if(postgres_db->open())` but `connect()` already did this.

In order to get this to work in your code, you could, for example, edit connect function to this:

```
QSqlDatabase* QSQLDbHelper::connect( const QString& server,
                                     const QString& databaseName,
                                     const QString& userName,
                                     const QString& password )
{
    db->setConnectOptions();
    db->setHostName(server);
    db->setDatabaseName(databaseName);
    db->setUserName(userName);
    db->setPassword(password);

    return db;
}
```

But of course then it wouldn't be doing actual connection, but rather set properties of it, so name would be slightly confusing.

Alternative is to test `postgres_db` for NULL and get access to private property `qSQLDbHelper->db` by creating getter of some sort or changing it to public.

Comment: Your answer is correct but I'm slightly confused what would I return on unsuccessful connection so that it does not crash.

Comment: if you can, then edit `connect` function to return `db->open()` and create new function to access property `QSQLDbHelper->db`. You can then use [lastError()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqldatabase.html#lastError) on it if `connect` returns false.

Comment: I've updated my answer with 2 ideas on how you can work around that. With this helper as is - you can't check for errors on connect. You will need to edit that class.